# Google database service

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

You want to process payment transactions in a point-of-sale application that will run on Google Cloud Platform. Your user base could grow exponentially, but you do not want to manage infrastructure scaling.
Which Google database service should you use?
A. Cloud SQL
B. BigQuery
C. Cloud Bigtable
D. Cloud Datastore

Few articles say data store cannot process payment transactions, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered AlloyDB? https://cloud.google.com/alloydb

Cloud SQL and AlloyDB would be great places to start. If you're coming from AWS, think of Cloud SQL as Google Cloud's version of RDS and AlloyDB as Amazon Aurora.

Given Aurora scales enough to handle the transaction load of Amazon.com itself, AlloyDB will likely be sufficient for your use case even if you need to significantly scale up in years to come.